# Very old date displaying incorrectly when unformatted

Tags: date-format, oracle-18c

At my organization, people have been entering unknown dates as "11/11/1111". When I run a query with the date field, the value shows up as "11/04/1111". However, if I format it as to_char(datefield,'mm/dd/yyyy'), it correctly shows up as "11/11/1111". Can anyone explain why this is? I assume it has something to do with Julian vs Gregorian dates, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: FWIW, in the Oracle Developer NLS settings, the date format is "MM/DD/YYYY".

Comment: Also making me suspect this is client-side, if I add to the query CASE WHEN datefield <> to_char(datefield,'mm/dd/yyyy') THEN 1 END, it returns null, so the server sees them as equal.

Comment: I can simplify this issue. If I run `SELECT to_date('11/11/1111','mm/dd/yyyy') FROM DUAL`, it returns a value of "11/04/1111".

Comment: I just tried `SELECT to_date('11/11/1111','mm/dd/yyyy') FROM DUAL` at SQL Fiddle, and THERE it returns "1111-11-18T00:00:00Z" -- 7 days _later_, instead of 7 days earlier.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is related to the Julian vs. Gregorian calendar. In the Gregorian calendar, 10/4/1582 was followed by 10/15/1582. In Oracle, `to_date(10/15/1582)` returns 10/15/1582, `to_date(10/14/1582)` to 10/05/1582 ALSO return 10/15/1582 (because, sure, those dates don't exist). Then, `to_date(10/04/1582)` returns 9/24/1582. Dates prior to that are offset by 10; the number changes as leap day discrepancies arise. So the date inputted is Gregorian and the date displayed is Julian. I still don't know why it's displaying a Julian date given the NLS settings.

Answer (score -3):

Interestingly, I don't see this in SQL Server (2019).

```
select
    [mydata]
    , cast([mydata] as varchar(20))
    , dateadd(dd, 1, [mydata])
from (
    select cast('11/11/1111' as date) as [mydata]
) as L1
```

[image: Results]

Comment: The question relates to Oracle not SQL Server